# The import org.apache.wicket cannot be resolved in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, m2e

I just installed **wicket plugin for eclipse** and have set all the environment variables also. But when I run `mvn -version` in command prompt it showing correct version.

But in Eclipse when I import the package it is showing the error the `import org.apache.wicket` cannot be resolved.

Can anybody come up with solution or suggestion?

Comment: How is maven and wicket related? Are you using maven as a build tool? If so how does your pom.xml look like - and have you installed some Maven plugin (like m2eclipse) for Eclipse?

Comment: Yes i installed m2e.If i want import wicket library then what i want to do....?

Comment: Are you opening your project as a MAVEN project in Eclipse?

Comment: No I'm opening as a JavaEE project.

Comment: Ok, does it get Maven dependencies and stuff? If not then you probably need to add some `wicket.jar`s to your project. If you're using maven you should add them to your `pom.xml`, for Eclipse JavaEE projects without Maven I think you need to add them manually. Also, how is the `maven -version` relevant to this question if you're not building and managing dependencies with Maven?